# occurred using the connection to database 'ESCRestaurantDB' on server '.\SQLEXPRESS'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

```cs
[HttpPost("add/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int userId, CategoryDto categoryDto)
{
    if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
        return Unauthorized();

    categoryDto.UserId = userId;


    var category = _mapper.Map<Category>(categoryDto);

    _repo.Add(category);

    if (await _unitOfWork.Complete())
        return Ok("Added successfully");

    throw new Exception("Adding Category Falid To Save");
}
```

This is my Controller, I don't know what should I do, why this Error was shown.

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using QRmenu.API.Dtos;
using QRmenu.API.Models;

namespace QRmenu.API.Helpers
{
    public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<User, UserForDetailedDto>();
            CreateMap<Item, ItemToReturnDto>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemImages, opt =>
               {
                   opt.MapFrom(src => src.ItemImages);
               });
                 
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Automapper code.

I need help to resolve this problem.

[image: i don't know why this error Showen][1]]

Comment: _"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."_ seems pretty self-evident to me. Considering this looks like a mapping error (i.e. when you call `mapper.Map<TargetType>(sourceObject)`), it would be useful for you to include that code. Without a [mcve] we can't help.

Comment: If it's self-evident, help

Comment: Well, it says that you've tried to use a mapping pair that is unsupported. It goes on to explain that you've tried to map `object` to `Category`. You have no mapping defined for that. You also haven't provided a [mcve]: you've provided the mapping configuration but no example of where this error is occurring.

Comment: can u show my code now

Comment: Clearly we needed to see the code from the CategoryController's Add method.

Comment: @John i pasted it , pls can u help me now?

Comment: `CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();` defines a map FROM `Category` TO `CategoryDto`. You're attempting a map from `CategoryDto` TO `Category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I haven't computer with development enviroment with me to test, but I thing you forgot put return statment in opt lambda funtion:

CreateMap<Item, ItemToReturnDto>() .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemImages, opt => {**return** opt.MapFrom(src => src.ItemImages); }

If you could paste some more code of how you is call map funtion, we could help you.

Comment: i pasted my code can u help now?

Comment: using AutoMapper;
using QRmenu.API.Dtos;
using QRmenu.API.Models;

namespace QRmenu.API.Helpers
{
    public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<User, UserForDetailedDto>();
            CreateMap<Item, ItemToReturnDto>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemImages, opt =>               
                   opt.MapFrom(src => src.ItemImages); //remove brackets to fix lambda expression
               );
                 
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();
            }
    }
}

Comment: error still , u can show my controller now

Comment: Hi mohame mostfa,

Problem is you try map  categoryDto to Category  

var category = _mapper.Map<Category>(categoryDto);

But you mapper configuration is mapping Category to Categroy DTO. CreateMap function syntax is CreateMap<SourceType,TarjetType> 

You can fix adding:

CreateMap<CategoryDto, Category>();

Or change map configuration to 

CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>().ReverseMap();